MyBatisのfetchSizeが効かず、全件取得される。どうすればよい？
遅延読み込みは問題なく動いています。ご教授の方お願いします。
期待している動作
membersの要素数フェッチ効かせて10件ごと取得したい
実際の動作
フェッチ効かずに全件取得される
環境
mybatis-3.5.16.jar
postgresql-42.7.2.jar

Team -> Member
class Team {
    
    private long id;
    private String name;

    private List<Member> members;

    // setter / getter ...  
}

class Member {
    
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long teamId;    

    private Team team;

    // setter / getter ...  
}

TeamMapper.xml
<resultMap id="resultMapTeam" type="Team">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <!-- auto-mapping -->

    <collection property="members" column="id" fetchType="lazy" select="MemberMapper.getAllByTeamId"/>
<resultMap/>

<select id="getById" resultMap="resultMapTeam">
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        teams
    WHERE
        id = #{id}
<select/>

MemberMapper.xml
<resultMap id="resultMapMember" type="Member">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <!-- auto-mapping -->

    <association property="team" column="teamId" fetchType="lazy" select="TeamMapper.getById"/>
<resultMap/>

<select id="getAllByTeamId" resultMap="resultMapMember" fetchSize="10">
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        members
    WHERE
        teamId = #{teamId}
<select/>


fetchSize属性は、SELECT結果に影響を与えません。(質問文の例だと)Teamレコードごとのmembersの要素数を10以下にしたい、ということでしょうか?

@ren130302 既にコメントが付いていますが、"期待される動作" と "実際の動作" について詳しい説明が必要ですね。あと java.sql.Statement#setFetchSize() の効果はドライバによって異なるので （例） DB とドライバのバージョンを追加してください。

@ren130302 fetchSize を指定しても、最終的に全ての Member オブジェクトが members に格納されるので、メモリの節約効果はありません（ドライバが内部的に 10 行ずつ取得する、というだけです）。最終的に members に格納される Member の数を制限したいのであれば、LIMIT 句を指定して getAllByTeamId の結果行数を制限する必要があります。

@ave さん　なるほど、SQL文のほうで制限かけてあげる必要があったんですね！ありがとうございます！！
